# Synchronous Filters with AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, angular-filters

I'm working with AngularFire and I'm trying to make a filter with a query to my firebase database, but when I want to return the result, it doesn't execute it.

My html:

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(office, job) in user.sucursales"><span>@{{office | searchOffice:company.$id }} </span> - @{{ job }} </li>
 </ul>
```

My filter:

```
app.filter('searchOffice', ['$firebaseObject', function($firebaseObject){
    return function(office, company){
        var ref_office = firebase.database().ref('sucursales').child(company).child(office);
        var office2 = $firebaseObject(ref_office);
        var office_name = 'hello';
        office2.$loaded().then(function(x){
            var office_name = x.nombre
            console.log(office_name); 
            return office_name;
        })
    }
}])
```

When I print the `console.log(office_name)` it gives me a correct result, the office's name, but when I want to return that result, is like don't get that part of the code. What can I am doing wrong?

Hope can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Your returning the filtered value when the promise resolves. This doesn't affect the filter at all. I think that even if you'd return the promise, the filter would still not work as expected. I don't think filters are capable of waiting for a returned promise to resolve.